# cancancan ability returns false but is still accessible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I have a standard cancancan setup. The Article model has an attribute `approved`. Then standard setup:

```rb
# articles controller

load_and_authorize_resource only: [:index, :show] 

def show 
end
```

```rb
# ability.rb

    # Solution 1
    # can :show, Article, { approved: true }


    # Solution 2
    can [:show], [Article] do |article|
      article.approved? 
    end
```

When I try either of the solutions, the results return as expected in the console or debugger (i.e. `ability.can?(:show, @article)` returns true if the article has been approved, and false otherwise).

The strange thing is, the show view is still accessible in the browser, when the `false` returned above clearly states that it shouldn't be accessible.

I can't work out why?

Answer (score 0):

After much help debugging in another forum, we never figured out why the above didn't work. But the desired behaviour was implemented by not using `load_and_authorize_resource`, and instead placing this in the controller action:

```
authorize! :show, @article
```

I'd be very curious to understand why this approach works, but the initial approach doesn't.